# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

Tags: opencv, cmake

I have downloaded the source code of the face-analysis SDK from http://face.ci2cv.net/. Now I am trying to get it running. I downloaded all the necessary software and followed the installation instructions. When I try to execute cmake [options] .. I get an error.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21(find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any of the following names:
OpenCVConfig.cmake
opencv-comfig.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory 
containing one of the above files. If OpenCV provides a separate development package or SDK, 
be sure it has been installed.
```

The CMakeLists.txt looks like this

```
# -*-cmake-*-
PROJECT(CSIRO-FaceAnalysis-SDK)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

#set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE true)

# Default values for options
if(NOT DEFINED OpenCV_PREFIX)
  set(OpenCV_PREFIX ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
endif()


  set(OpenCV_PREFIX C:/Program Files/Development/opencv/build)
endif(
# Configurable options
OPTION(WITH_GUI "Build the GUI" OFF)

# Third party libraries
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core highgui imgproc objdetect
  PATHS ${OpenCV_PREFIX}/lib/cmake/
        ${OpenCV_PREFIX}/share/OpenCV/
  NO_DEFAULT_PATH) # For some reason CMake uses its defaults before the above paths.
```

Please help me, I have no idea what to do.

Thanks, B

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Check that OpenCV is installed on your system. Note the folder where it is installed. For example: `C:\OpenCV`
2. Execute CMake with a command line similar to

> cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:\OpenCV" ..

OR

find the folder containing OpenCVConfig.cmake (for example C:\OpenCV\build\x86\vc10\lib) and pass it to CMake via the variable OpenCV_DIR

> cmake -DOpenCV_DIR="C:\OpenCV\build\x86\vc10\lib" ..

In both cases, I think the provider of the code you try to compile commited an error by putting `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` in the `find_package(OpenCV ...)`. If nothing work, re-try after removing this flag.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked. But I am already facing the next problem.In the documentation it says: When CMake has successfully configured the project, issue "make". From the context I get that I need this make command to complete the build. However, when I simply enter make in my cmd line it says that there is no such command. Can you please help me? Thanks, B

Comment: If you are on Windows it depends on your environment. Try `mingw-make` instead if you want to use GCC from MinGW. Try `nmake` if you use MSVC compiler. Anyway, I suggest you to read some basic documentation on CMake usage, and particularity of your platform (Windows I guess). Many questions on StackOverflow will also help you. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219479/using-cmake-with-windows-7-visual-studio-2010-and-the-command-line

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I already read some of the basic documentations on CMake. But I do not really get it. I am using Windows 8.1 and I have installed visual Studio so I have access to nmake.exe. Does this bring me any further?

Comment: So after running CMake, you should be able to run nmake to achieve compilation. What problem do you face?

Comment: After the configuration with CMake is done. I try to run nmake but I get the message: the command nmake cannot be found.

Comment: I quote your words: `I have installed visual Studio so I have access to nmake.exe`. Do you have access to nmake or not?

Please create a new question for this specific issue. It is too complex to be answered in comments of another answer

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem a few days ago and this is the code I used to install it onto my system and make it in a way for CMakeLists.txt to understand how to locate those files. This process works for other packages as well.

`cd ~/`

`git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git`

`cd opencv`

`mkdir install`

`cd install`

`cmake ../`

`make`

`sudo make install`

NOTE: It took a long time for opencv to make because of its complexity and size but I am sure there is a way to download and make only certain parts you need. I did not do that because I did not know how.

Answer (score 0):

The standalone OPENCV lib install can solve this issue itself

```
apt install libopencv-dev
```